# What's the derivative of $f(x) = \cos (x) ^{\ln(3x)}$?

Tags: derivatives

I don't understand where or how many times I need to apply the chain rule.

Comment: The form of this function is a bit tricky.  I would convert/rewrite it to a form $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$ so that it would have a more familiar look.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Let $\cos x^{ \ln (3x) } = y  $. Then

$$ \ln(3x) \ln( \cos x) = \ln y $$

Now, apply implicit differentiation:

$$ \frac{1}{x} \ln( \cos x ) + \ln(3x) \frac{ - \sin x }{\cos x } = \frac{y'}{y}$$

Now, solve for $y'$